# Reading NIC's Description and MAC Address Win32 API

Tags: windows, winapi, win64, windows-kernel

I am using `GetAdaptersInfo()` to **READ** the NIC's `Description` and using it. However, I recently came to know that, someone can modify this in Windows Registry, as there is a key called `Friendly Name` in HKLM tree section.

For me it is somewhere in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\ROOT...

My problem is, not to get into this problem and get the `Description` field which in not impacted by change in `Friendly Name` field.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? Write access to HKLM requires administrative privileges. You cannot protect your code against a (local) system administrator. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I need to detect if there is a group of people who is using a specific VPN server. Trying to get the NIC description and send it to server. Server will decide if service should be allowed. I don't have to modify registry data. I am rather using WinAPI to get the NIC description. But what if people deceive this strategy  by changing the said registry key.

Comment: @ultimatecause a user-defined description is not a good way to uniquely identify a NIC, and certainly is not something you should be transmitting to a server for said identification

Comment: I am not modifying the Description. The point is that this group of people violate license limitations by connecting using a VPN. However, if the clients report the VPN NIC to server, then the server can identify the similarity and can stop this violation.

Comment: If people can change this registry key (admins), they can also ... change your code since it's installed on the machine too. What you're currently doing (checking reg some value) is just "raising the bar", so you can stop, you've done the maximum you could. Or think a whole different security strategy.

Comment: You can check [`MACAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter) to see if it helps. A MAC address is a unique 48-bit number assigned to the network adapter by the manufacturer.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Any idea on how to read UAA MAC? I am not interested in LAA.

Comment: @ultimatecause What do you mean by *UAA*?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT UAA (Universally Administered Address), is the MAC Address which is burnt into the device chip. LAA is Locally Administered Address which can be modified by OS and that modified value is what is seen by external world.

Comment: @ultimatecause `GetAdaptersInfo` can get the [hardware address for the adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_info).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT - That is LAA not UAA.

Comment: @ultimatecause How do you know that?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I have checked it. If UAA is modified, it goes into LAA.

Comment: @ultimatecause If it is a virtual adapter, its MAC address is at software level instead of hardware/firmware level. So it can not be used to identify a unique machine. Could you confirm the following information: 1. Are you the VPN server owner and you want to control the access of the VPN? 2. There are different roles like physical machine, virtual machine and user etc. Do you want to identify a user or a physical machine?